# How do I compose an existing Moose role into a class at runtime?

Tags: perl, roles, moose

Say I define an abstract My::Object and concrete role implementations My::Object::TypeA and My::Object::TypeB. For maintainability reasons, I'd like to not have a hardcoded table that looks at the object type and applies roles. As a DWIMmy example, I'm looking for something along these lines in My::Object:

```
has => 'id' (isa => 'Str', required => 1);

sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;

  my $type = $self->lookup_type(); ## Returns 'TypeB'
  {"My::Object::$type"}->meta->apply($self);
}
```

Letting me get a My::Object with My::Object::TypeB role applied by doing the following:

```
my $obj = My::Object(id = 'foo')
```

Is this going to do what I want or am I on the entirely wrong track?

Edit: I simplified this too much; I don't want to have to know the type when I instantiate the object, I want the object to determine its type and apply the correct role's methods appropriately. I've edited my question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried it?

```
$perl -Moose -E'
     sub BUILD { my ($self, $p) = @_; my $role = qq[Class::$$p{role}]; $role->meta->apply($self) };
     package Class::A; use Moose::Role; has a => (is => q[ro], default => 1);
     package main; say Class->new(role => q[A])->dump'
```

Yields:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'a' => 1
           }, 'Class::MOP::Class::__ANON__::SERIAL::1' );
```

This appears to be what you want. Cleaned up the code in the oose.pm call is:

```
package Class; 
use Moose;
sub BUILD { 
    my ($self, $p) = @_;
    my $role = qq[Class::$$p{role}];
    $role->meta->apply($self);
}

package Class::A;
use Moose::Role;

has a => ( is => 'ro', default => 1 );

package main;
Class->new(role => 'A');
```

Comment: No, I hadn't. Was more of a best practices question making sure I'd understood the ->meta documentation correctly and that I wasn't going down the wrong path.

Comment: Moose, and Perl in general is very good about being an experimental language. If you have a question, try it and see what the results are. If you don't understand the results *then* ask … you'll save yourself a lot of time waiting on someone else to confirm/deny your hypothesis.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`MooseX::Traits`](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/MooseX-Traits-0.11/lib/MooseX/Traits.pm), it will turn your role into a *trait* that can be applied at runtime, then you just call:

```
   # Where Class is a class that has `use MooseX::Traits`;
   # And TypeB is a simple role
   Class->new_with_traits( traits => [qw/TypeB/] )

   # or even the new, and now preferred method.
   Class->with_traits('TypeB')->new();
```

Comment: I've edited my question to make my question clearer. As far as I can tell, MooxeX::Traits requires the type to be known at object instantiation. I want the object to determine its type and apply the required role, rather than requiring it to be part of the API.

Answer (score 1):

After the question update I'll give it another crack: `with()` is just a function call.

```
package Class;
use Moose;

BEGIN {
  with ( map "MyObject::$_", qw/TypeA TypeB/ );
}
```

Also, you can reference the current package with the perl constant `__PACKAGE__`.